# Is Simplified Technical English based on American English or British English?

Tags: dialects, technical

Simplified Technical English was originally developed for use in aviation maintenance manuals, but has expanded beyond this use into a variety of technical fields. It is a "separate" controlled language consisting of a highly restricted subset of simple English words. Are these words are derived from American English, British English, both, or neither?

Comment: Is this the same as [Simplified Technical English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Technical_English)? A quick look at their dictionary should tell you whether they use, for example, *color* or *colour*. Since it's standardized by a European organization, I'll guess it's *colour*.

Comment: Whoops, that's what I meant. Edited to fix.

Comment: Looking around, it seems an American industry association was also involved.  The late 1970s and 1980s.  With English the language of aviation, both commercial and military aircraft needed maintenance manuals that could be unambiguously understood throughout Western Europe.  I bet Eastern Europe used them too.  Could be an interesting bit of history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in ASD-STE 100 (issue 7, January 2017):

> STE approved meanings are based on American English (Merriam-Webster's
>   dictionary).

Rule 1.14:

> Use American English spelling.